# Can I reference input:text as an #id?

Tags: jquery, input, filter

I'm looking to create a "filtering input field" that eliminates tiles from a page that don't match the input.

So far I have this...

HTML -

```
<input name="filter" type="text" value="Find who you're looking for" />
<a href='#' id='b_submit'>Submit</a>

<article id='JohnS'>Content</article>
<article id='BobG'>Content</article>
<article id='SamL'>Content</article>
<article id='RonaldY'>Content</article>
```

Script -

```
$("#b_submit").click(function() {

    var filter_text = $('input:text').val();
    //this sets filter_text as the input value

    $('article:not(??not sue what to call here??)').fadeOut();
    //this is where I need help, I need to call the value as an #id to eliminate non-matching articles. 

    });
```

What's the proper syntax to do this? Am I over complicating simple filtering? Help? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
$('article:not(#'+filter_text+')').fadeOut();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GKj66/

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
$('article:not(:contains("' + filter_text + '"))').fadeOut();
```

Comment: Won't this fade out articles that match the filter text?

Comment: @AaronBenjamin No problemo.